# Send Authorization Token to webservice using soapclient PHP

Tags: php, soap

Hi Guys I have tried passing some parameters to Some WebService

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems sending SOAP auth Headers in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313390/problems-sending-soap-auth-headers-in-php)

Comment: Hey @NeerajKumar Im required to pass Authorization. Not Username and Password and If its the Same, how do i declare the Authorization Bearer on the request? Kindly assist. Thanks

Comment: @NeerajKumar This post does not address bearer authentication, which more people have questions about. So this is a valid question.